# use onMounted Hook

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I'm using nuxt3 with vue3 for my website.
But I have problem when using onMounted hook.

here is my vue page.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { onMounted } from '@vue/runtime-core';

  onMounted(() => {
    console.log('myheader mounted');
  })
</script>

<template>
    <h1>test</h1>
</template>
```

I get this errors:

```
[Vue warn]: onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.
```

It makes me confused...... T.T

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nuxt requires [importing the hooks from `vue`](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/3526#issuecomment-1060018666), not `@vue/runtime-core`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  // import { onMounted } from '@vue/runtime-core'; ❌
  import { onMounted } from 'vue'; ✅

  onMounted(() => {
    console.log('myheader mounted');
  })
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-using-hooks-in-script-setup?file=components/MyComponent.vue)

Or use [auto imports](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/auto-imports#vue-auto-imports) instead. That is, omit the `import`, and let Nuxt automatically import `onMounted` from the correct package:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  // onMounted auto imported ✅

  onMounted(() => {
    console.log('myheader mounted');
  })
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-using-hooks-in-script-setup-a5czpt?file=components/MyComponent.vue)